# Are there default encryption features to encrypt/decrypt strings in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography

I googled but mostly found links to 3rd part libraries for encryption/decryption works. However, I saw [Security](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security) articles on the Apple site, though without examples.

Can you please show me an example of a simple encrypt/decrypt a string with a key function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security and CommonCrypto are low level frameworks. They only provide security primitives, not a full encrypted data format. It is challenging to build a secure format out of the primitives, and most examples you'll find online are insecure. Either the author did not know how to build a secure format, or the author assumes you know how to take what they've written and finish building a secure format.

There is no such thing as "decrypting a string" in the way that you likely mean. All encryption functions generate raw bytes. If you want a string, convert it to base64 or hex or whatever. Some libraries automatically add this, but it often leads to strange artifacts like double-base64-encoded data.

If you want a cross-platform "out of the box" encryption format, see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) or [libSodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium). Both of these convert data-to-data. If you want strings, just encode and decode the data as you like (usually as base64 or hex).

Comment: Note that there is such a thing as Format Preserving Encryption or FPE. In general it's easier to encode to bytes and then - if required - to encode the ciphertext back to a string though, as in the answer above. Libraries that support FPE seem scarce.

Comment: I'm somewhat missing the *character encoding* (e.g. UTF-8) required to generate the binary plaintext in the answer above. Currently it only talks about encoding the ciphertext.

Comment: It's a fair point about FPE, though it is not only rare to find implementations, it is even harder to make them secure (particularly in a general case). You can wind up trading security for compatibility if you're not very careful (and often even if you are). But yes, there is such a thing.

Comment: And yes, once you have decrypted your data, if you want to turn it into text, you'll have to use `String.init?(data:encoding:)`, but I believe this will be commonly understood among Swift developers.

Comment: OK, given the type system of Swift I guess the warning about character encoding is not really needed. You'll have to encode / decode anyway to go from text to binary and binary to text... As long as nobody tries to RSA encrypt character values anyway, but I guess if that happens all is lost :P

Answer (score -1):

What I have found you can have a look at this url : [Swift Default Encryption](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applearchive/encrypting_and_decrypting_a_string)